# Why does Ubuntu on my laptop shut itself down?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

A week ago, I accidentally split some water around the touchpad of my Thinkpad laptop   (underneath is my RAM), and then after a while it shut down itself. I opened the laptop and wiped off the water inside, and then I could start it successfully.

After two days of running, it shut itself down when I was browsing  and clicking on the Internet. The same problem has happened three times so far.

- The cpu temperature has been normal because it is shown in real time in my desktop panel, but I don't know if the temperatures of the other components of the laptop are normal.
- I don't know if the shutdown is the remaining symptom of water getting inside my laptop.

Is there some way in Ubuntu (18.04) to investigate the reason of automatically shutting down?

Comment: Remove the battery, if possible. Bury laptop in uncooked rice, in a sealed container (plastic bag will work). The rice will absorb all the water in the air inside the container, the laptop water will evaporate into the air, eventually. Keep the container sealed for a week (YMMV, depends on how much water, how much rice).

Comment: It is already dried. The water accident was a week ago. But now the laptop shuts itself down after about two days' run, while I am clicking on the internet

Comment: have you check what `sudo dmesg` says? any errors there? Go to your `/var/log` and find releveant `syslog` which contains the moment when your computer shut down.

Comment: @dgan Thank you. How far back does it store the messages? How can I locate the messages from some time to another?

Comment: unless you deleted them ALL of system messages are stored there. Only the last `syslog` file is in plain text form, others are usually `.gz`-ipped. If the last doesn't go back enough, try to un-`gzip` them, and look for clues.

Comment: @dgan Thank you. I updated here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642851/does-ubuntu-log-hardware-abnormality-and-can-i-perform-hardware-testing-and-fin